# Create a command, a job recursive in laravel or something like that

Tags: laravel

I want to create a function in laravel that is executed once and only when finished it is executed again. It doesn't help me that it runs every second because if for some reason it is delayed, results would be duplicated. I wanted to try creating a recursive command but it doesn't allow me to create infinite loops, can you suggest me something? (sorry if my english is not perfect).

Comment: We could do with a little more detail as it's not entirely clear what you want. However, I think [events](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/events) might work for you. Basically fire an event once your function has completed. This could be from within the function or when it returns to the calling function. If you can add some code examples that might clear things up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `withoutOverlapping` method:

```php
$schedule->command('emails:send')->withoutOverlapping();
```

Learn more here: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/scheduling#preventing-task-overlaps